# Swift 4 AFNetworking typealias conversion error

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, swift4, type-alias

I'm migrating to Swift 4 and I have the following typealias:

`typealias AFDataSuccess =  (task: URLSessionDataTask, responseObject: Any?)`

but I'm having trouble converting it as shown in the attached image:

[image]

Comment: it would be easier to convert using _Alamofire_, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like this :

```
manager.post(route.url, parameters: params, progress: nil, success: { (task: URLSessionDataTask, response: Any?) in
    print(response)
}) { (task: URLSessionDataTask, error: Error) in
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes @holex is Absolutely right you should use Alamofire because the better approach for networking in Swift by using Alamofire

here is link https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

Use Alamofire . This is best with swift Networking and use in simple way like this->

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

if let json = response.result.value {
    print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
}

if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
}
```

}